# GET 400 and Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, axios

Even though I checked with if(e.target.value === ""), it gives an error when the textarea is empty.

```
onFirstChange = async (e) => {

const response = await axios.get("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + key +
    "&text=" +
    e.target.value +
    "&lang=en");

if (e.target.value === "") {
  this.setState({
    firstArea: "",
    lastArea: "",
  });
} else {
  this.setState({
    firstArea: e.target.value,
    lastArea: response.data.text,
  });
}


};
```

Textareas :

```
<textarea
            className="form-control"
            id="firstArea"
            name="firstArea"
            rows="5"
            placeholder="Enter"
            defaultValue={this.state.firstArea}
            onKeyUp={this.onFirstChange}
          ></textarea>
<textarea
                className="form-control"
                id="lastArea"
                name="lastArea"
                rows="5"
                placeholder=" "
                defaultValue={this.state.lastArea}
                onKeyUp={this.onLastChange}
              ></textarea>
```

Errors :

GET 400

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Comment: You probably calling your API endpoint in a wrong way. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: When textarea is not empty it doesn't give an error and it runs.

Comment: Looking at your code it is hard to tell how the value inside textarea can affect the API call. Is your API endpoint dependent on the value inside textarea or is it a plain string. I think you need to add a few more details, to get  a better response.

Comment: But you are calling your API everytime no matter if target value is empty or not.

Comment: I am using yandex translate api. It dependent on the value inside textarea.

Comment: are you able to call the APIs(i.e. axios call) in console successfully? I think you will get better idea about your problem in that way

Comment: I updated question. I wrote api content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new edit makes it clear. You cannot send an API call with empty text parameter. That is why you are getting an error only in that condition.

Call it only when there is some value in your text area.

```
en though I checked with if(e.target.value === ""), it gives an error when the textarea is empty.

onFirstChange = async (e) => {



if (e.target.value === "") {

  this.setState({
    firstArea: "",
    lastArea: "",
  });
} else{

const response = await axios.get("https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + key +
    "&text=" +
    e.target.value +
    "&lang=en");


  this.setState({
    firstArea: e.target.value,
    lastArea: response.data.text,
  });
}


};
```

Tip: Before using API calls directly in code, try to tets them using tools like Postman/cURL or even simply opening the url in browser(if possible).